# How to install linux environment dependencies (apt-get install) on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an app engine instance that makes use of WeasyPrint, however to get it to run I need a few dependencies such as "cairo pango gdk-pixbuf libxml2 libxslt libffi".

I'm not sure how to trigger an apt-get on startup of my instance.

How do I make sure these are installed before my application runs?

Comment: Which App Engine? You cannot run `apt-get` on Standard - you do not have access to the OS.

Comment: This is on a flex instance...

Comment: The answer as discovered in the question linked by the duplicate, tells me I should use RUN apt-get install -y in a dockerfile with a custom env set in the app.yaml in a flex engine.

Comment: Did you successfully get this to work?  I have the same issue and I can't figure out at all how to get these dependencies to install correctly.

Answer (score -2):

You can install dependencies only on an App Engine Flex or Compute Engine instance. App Engine standard does not allow modifying runtime environment. To have a python dependency installed simply add it to your "requirements.txt". Check [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/flexible/hello_world) for an example

***requirements.txt***

```
Flask==0.12.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
```